# Help in calling a javascript function from php or html

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

This might be simple to someone, but I am a bit of a novice and searched everywhere. I have a javascript function.

```
mkfile : function(fm) {
```

I am trying to execute this from an on click command.

Any ideas. Sorry Im a bit of a dunce in this, but I have tried everything and nothing happens.

Comment: onclick="function(arg);" doesn't work? You'll need to post more code

Comment: Your JavaScript snippet does not make any sense. It is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Matt, I think that's javascript's namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Use the attribute `onclick` as follows: `<a onclick="javascript:mkfile()" >Bob</a>`. You don't have to have the `javascript:` before-hand but it helps in browsers like IE (don't even get me started).

By the way, your code is wrong, it should be

```
function mkfile(fm) {
  // your code
}
```

Don't hesistate to ask if you don't understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Without more code it is difficult to tell what you are doing wrong, but normally it goes like this:

```
<button id="foo">Click me!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    }

</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNNDn/)

There are several ways of binding event handlers. I suggest to read [*quirksmode.org - Introduction to Events*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) , [*MDC - Event handlers*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Event_Handlers) and [*MDC - The DOM and JavaScript*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_JavaScript) and also follow the links given there ;)

Comment: This is not 'from' HTML or PHP, but still valid. (And it doesn't include or reference to the question's code)

Comment: @Fred: 1) Writing event handlers in the HTML code is old school and should not be done anymore anyway. Besides that, *calling JavaSCript from HTML* is very much open to interpretation imo. 2) If I read *help in calling a javascript function from php* then I assume the OP has little to zero knowledge about DOM scripting and does not know the best way.

Comment: Wow. That was quick. Thanks for all the replies.The original code function I did not write. It does work bizarrely. I am working with elfinder. Its a file manager. I will try all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, it's not really possible to see what is wrong with your code without seeing more of it. But the small portion you posted (with its `name:value`) is valid only in a couple of circumstances, both of which are somewhat common patterns of JS design:

```
// Pattern one
var makeMyObject = function() {
    var privateVar = 'a private member';
    var privateMethod = function() {};
    var objOut = {
        mkDir:function() {/*more code*/},
        mkFile:function() {/*more code*/},
        delFile:function() {/*more code*/}
    };
    return objOut;
};
myObject = makeMyObject();
myObject.mkFile();

// Pattern two
var myObject = {
    mkDir:function() {/*more code*/},
    mkFile:function() {/*more code*/},
    delFile:function() {/*more code*/}
};
myObject.mkFile();
```

If this is what you have, the way you can bind this to an onclick in your HTML code is:

```
<a href="/some_page.html" onclick="myObject.mkFile()">Click here</a>
```

Or in your JS,

```
domMyAnchorElement.onclick = myObject.mkFile; // Note there are no parens because you are binding the function, not invoking it.
```

Comment: Still cant get it to work. I want to attach it here. Is there a way. You can see the js script here. In there you will see the mkfile function. http://elrte.org/redmine/projects/elfinder/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/js/elFinder.ui.js Dont know if you have seen elfinder but it looks quite good.

Comment: I found solution. http://elrte.org/redmine/boards/2/topics/1246?r=1883 if anyone interested.